# How to record the RAM usage during Python and C++ run time?

Tags: python, 20.04, ram, c++

I want to compare the RAM consumption for a Python versus C++ implementation of a code I have written. Essentially I am looking for a command like:

```
<record ram> python3 main.py
```

and

```
<record this runtime ram> g++ main.cpp
```

Is is possible to record RAM for a specific task like this in Linux Ubuntu?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the text file `/prof/self/stat` after all the memory allocation takes place. Its fields are described [here](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php//proc/pid/stat). In linux we refer to two kinds of memory:

- Resident Set Size (RSS) is how much memory is allocated to the process and in in RAM,
- Virtual Memory Size (VMZ) is how much memory is allocated including swapped out memory and memory allocated by shared libraries.

From the `stat` file read `vsize` and `rss`. After reading this you can find the size in `kb` using the following in C++.

```
#include <unistd.h>
...

long page_size_kb = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) / 1024; // in case x86-64 is configured to use 2MB pages
vm_usage     = vsize / 1024.0;
resident_set = rss * page_size_kb;
```

In Python you can use `os.sysconf("SC_PAGE_SIZE")` to get the `PAGE_SIZE` and do the equivalent calculation.

You can also explore [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) for this purpose.